# My code spent long time when I use mutex_lock inside loop

Tags: c, pthreads, locking

When I use mutex_lock inside loop, my code spends huge time in execution, and I can't get the output.
I know `lock ()` take time, but not as this!

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int x = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *fnC()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        x++;
    }
    printf(" %d", x);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

int main()
{
    int rt1, rt2;
    pthread_t t1, t2;
    /* Create two threads */
    if ((rt1 = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &fnC, NULL)))
        printf("Thread creation failed: %d\n", rt1);
    if ((rt2 = pthread_create(&t2, NULL, &fnC, NULL)))
        printf("Thread creation failed: %d\n", rt2);
    /* Wait for both threads to finish */
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Anyone can explain this?

Comment: You should explain why you're loop-locking the mutex. Unless the mutex is specifically attributed to recursion (via attribute of `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE`, which you're *not* doing), consecutive locks on  the same thread without interceding unlocks invokes UB. Unrelated, your thread function is not pthread compliant. A proper thread proc is *specifically* `void *(*pfn)(void*)`. Yours is `void*(*pfn)()`, and as-bad, never returns a value though it promises to do so. Those are the rules; we don't make them up as we go along.

Comment: `pthread_mutex_lock` outside (i.e. before)  the `for`-loop

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) { pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);`  you are locking it twice, so the second one will endlessly wait..

Comment: I know I can do lock() outside loop , but my question why I can't get the output if I do previous code.

Comment: @mhmdmhidat, Kamil already told you.  The first thread to acquire the mutex attempts to acquire it again without first releasing it.  That deadlocks both threads.